# when is the WPF UI Update completed

Tags: wpf, user-interface, dispatcher

I have a problem with update UI in WPF. What I want to do is to capture the snapshot of my application. But the problem is the application has more than one UI status. For example, I have a TextBox and a Button in my application. When I click the Button, the TextBox will show number from 1 to 10, and I want to capture the UI status with number 3, 5, 7. Since WPF uses dispatcher to update the UI, I don’t know when the UI will be updated to 3,5,7. So I cannot get the correct time to capture the snapshot. How can I do this?

Comment: An obvious answer would be to subscribe to the `TextChanged` event of the `TextBox` and check the new content. But the question is not very clear. Maybe posting some code would help.

Answer (score 0):

Create A CustomTextBox class inherited from default textbox.
Then you can override the onRender Method. 
Which will give more control of the textbox render.

Hope this helps